# Can I change the ID of a asp.net control programatically - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a control

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAjax" runat="server" Text="Ajaxified" OnClick="btnAjax_Click" />
```

Now from the code behind I want to change the ID of the button

```
btnAjax.ID = "newButtonID";
```

But it is now working. Is it possible at the first place?

**EDIT**

I've created the control in the HTML mark up and not through code.

Comment: You can but I'm almost certain a call back should be necessary. (You'll have to render the control again so that the new ID is reflected in HTML). May I ask why you want to do this anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is possible and your code you posted will work.

I have a button and a text field

```
<asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" />
<input type="text" id="result" name="result" runat="server" />
```

On page load I change the ID of the button and then output the result to the text field.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button.ID = "OtherButton";
    result.Value = button.ID;
}
```

The result in the text field is "OtherButton"

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can that Property is both read and write [able].

I tried and yes the ID can be changed and its also reflected in rendered HTML.

**Update**

There is a [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) attribute which you can set to 'Static' that you can use to force asp.net into not changing the ID in rendered HTML.

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Comment: But it is not getting reflected while the page is rendered.

Comment: I've created the control in the mark up. How can I change the control ID in that case?

Comment: you can change that..*(sorry i was wrong before)* .. i tried and the change was reflected in rendered HTML... but remember asp.net prepends every server control's ID with its own string

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can imagine one would need to achieve something like this is to safely allow client script to interact with the button. If this is the case then I prefer to pass the control's clientID to the script:

```
var btnAjax = document.getElementById('<%=btnAjax.ClientID%>')
```

Or using jQuery:

```
$('#<%=btnAjax.ClientID%>')
```