# Have duplicate content on a single aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, frontend

Background: I am trying to implement a new layout for my company's enterprise website, and I've already set up the master page to swap between the old and new layouts based on a feature flag that is set. Now I want to restyle each page and be able to swap between the old and new content using that same feature flag. The problem is I can't duplicate Ids so now the back end code, which I don't want to touch, would need to be touched so that all duplicated controls work properly on the backend.

The way the old pages are styled it's not as easy to just swap out CSS files, all styles are embedded in the asp control itself, so this lead me to the solution below, but it complains about the duplicate control ids.

My question is, is there an easy way to do what I want to do here? Or is there some way I can have two controls on the same page with the same ID?

My primary area of development is ASP.NET MVC and I try to stay as far away from webforms as possible but the sheer number of pages we have that are aspx would be a slow process of converting each page to a new MVC view. So I just wanted to restyle the aspx pages for now.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server"></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button1"/>
    Feature flag is off
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="NewMainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button1"/>
    Feature flag is on
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an if stament to only render that required section

```
<% if(!Featureflag) { %>
   <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button1"/>
     Feature flag is off
</asp:Content>
<% } else { %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="NewMainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button1"/>
    Feature flag is on
</asp:Content>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Yes this works, but it still complains about the button1 being a duplicate id. Thats my main issue, im starting to think that im pushing webforms too far on this one.

Comment: I beleive you can change the ID of a server control at runtime.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142204/can-i-change-the-id-of-a-asp-net-control-programatically-asp-net

maybe try that?!?

Comment: Also I could change the ID of one of the buttons to "button2" but now the backend needs to be edited to use both button1 and button2. Which im trying to avoid.

Comment: That may work, i would still have to edit the back end code but only minimally. Let me play around with that for a bit.